# ubuntu 13 with windows 8 and updating ubunu it disappears from booting list

Tags: dual-boot

I have been working with Ubuntu 13 about a year and I have dual boot with windows 8.

Then a message appeared that Ubuntu needs updates and I accepted the updates and started updating.

After finishing and restarting ubuntu the machine started making load noise 
and after restarting more than one time the machine is working windows 8 only and Ubuntu disappeared from the booting list completely hope to rescue my files and programs installed because they are important to me.

Comment: try boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For recover your files or try to fix the system I recommend same thing, use a **LiveCD** or **LiveUSB** with Ubuntu.

If you don't have a CD/USB with Ubuntu [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) you can follow a tutorial about getting one USB Live on Windows.

Once you have a CD/DVD with Ubuntu just boot from CD/USB and hit on "Try Ubuntu..." and wait until Ubuntu loads.

**To recover Ubuntu installation**

You can try some things like fix/reinstall the ubuntu grub with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

You can follow this tutorial [Ubuntu Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

**To recover your files**

Just look for the internal hard disk and mount it, then copy the files you want to save to external device/cloud or where you want. Once you've saved all the data can reformat PC or delete linux partition.